# FullSimplify not simplifying expression containing the form Sin[n] where n is an integer

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have a function `f[n]` which give 0 for integer input, but `FullSimplify` doesn't work for it, why?

```
f[n_] := (Sin[1] - Sin[1 - n π] + E^(-I n π) (Sin[1] - Sin[1 + n π]))/(n π)
Table[f[n], {n, 1, 10}]
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], f[n]] // FullSimplify
```

How can I force it to work?

Comment: The `FullSimplify` is outside of the scope of the `Assuming` so it does not see the assumption. Change to `Assuming[Element[n, Integers], f[n] // FullSimplify]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mixing in the irrelevant use of `Table`.

```
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, 
 FullSimplify[
 (Sin[1] - Sin[1 - n π] + E^(-I n π) (Sin[1] - Sin[1 + n π]))/(n π)]
        ]
```

(*

0

*)

Comment: As you say, the `Table` is irrelevant so it is not the cause of the problem. The OP merely used the `Table` to demonstrate that the function evaluated to zero for integer arguments. The issue is whether or not the `FullSimplify` is within the scope of the `Assuming` and thereby sees the assumption.